# fibbonnacci. sequence UnboundLocalError

Tags: python-3.x

I've been working on this Fibbonacci sequence function. I am essentially returning a list of the Fibbonacci sequence by growing out a returned list respective to the number sequence that is generated by passing in a particular number. however I'm encountering an error within my for loop at the if statement within that for loop. it states UnboundLocalError: local variable 'new_list' referenced before assignment. Does anyone have a clue how to remedy this? Any help  will be appreciated. thanks

```
def fib_n(num):
if num < 0:
    print("You have entered incorrect output")
elif num == 0:
    new_list = []
else:
    for index in range(1,num):
        if index == 1 or index == 2:
            new_list.append(1)
            continue
        new_list.append(new_list[index - 1] + new_list[index - 2])
    return new_list
```

Comment: You might want to put `new_list = []` at the beginning of the function.

Comment: Oh, and fix the indentation of the last line.